# No Results, if $softDelete is activated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I do have the following class:

```
class BillProduct extends Eloquent {
  protected $softDelete = true;
  protected $guarded = array();
  public static $rules = array();
  protected $table = 't_billsproducts';
}
```

If I try to select a record using

```
$record = BillProduct::find($idProduct)
```

`$record` will be empty.

If I delete `protected $softDelete` from the class above, `$record` will contain the data...

There are no soft-deleted columns in the database - and I wonder, what happens here...

Any ideas?
Thanks

Dirk

Comment: check the raw query, afaik it something like `'where deleted_at is null` but that column in your table doesn't exist, hence, no result.

Comment: Thanks, NULL was the solution - I had "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in all the "deleted at"

Answer (score 0):

When you enable soft deletes in a model you need to add a column to the table called `deleted_at`. If you are using migrations you can do so by adding `$table->softDeletes()` to your Schema.

If you want to retrieve all records (including deleted ones) you can do this:

```
$records = Model::withTrashed()->get();
```

More info:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting